# React native Background geolocation updates IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

[This package](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)

> I need solution for i want to update location every 30 seconds.

I'm using this package for background geolocation updates when its working fine, but when i move my phone (iphone6) it send my location to firebase. I'm using location changes of this package because postTemplate is not working on IOS device and `stoOnStillActivity:true` for if activity is still it wont send location.

```
 BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
        locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.MEDIUM_ACCURACY,
        stationaryRadius: 10,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        debug: true,
        interval: 30000,
        stopOnStillActivity: true,
  })
```

This one sending location to firebase

```
 BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {
        BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(taskKey => {

            firestore()
                .collection('testlocation')
                .add({
                    name: 'DEVICE',
                    lat: location.latitude,
                    lon: location.longitude,
                    dat: new Date,
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Location added BITCH!')
                }).catch(e => console.log(e))

            console.log("Stark task started successfully", new Date, location.latitude, location.longitude)
            BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey)
        })
    })
```